# Lose connection to internet domain after downloading files via FTP

Tags: networking, firewall, ftp

I have a VM hosted at a cloud service provider. When I download many small files via FTP (server is IIS 8.5) the downloading stops after 20-30 files, and I get an error: **550 Data channel timed out**. I am accessing the VM using an IP address (as opposed to a domain name).

After this happens, I can no longer access my cloud provider's web site in a browser (in Chrome, I get: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT) from any machine on my home network. I can access the site fine using my phone's cellular data connection.

So I disconnect my FTP client (FileZilla), and after a few minutes I can access my provider's web site again from all machines on my LAN. And I can also connect via FTP again, and repeat the whole process.

During this period of downtime, I cannot access files via FTP on my VM, nor can I access my provider's web site by name or IP. But I can ping the provider's website IP just fine.

Also, I cannot initiate a new remote desktop connection to my VM during this "outage" time. If I am already connected to the VM using RD, then I can maintain that connection and access the server during the "downtime". Just no new connections.

So this does not seem to be an issue on my VM or my cloud provider; It must be something on my router (ASUS RT-AC66R) or my ISP. Since I have no firewall enabled on my router, how can I troubleshoot this?

*NOTE: After typing all this up, I realize SU may not be the appropriate venue for this inquiry, but I thought I should start here, considering the competence level of users.*

Comment: This is an appropriate forum.  At a guess, the problem is that FTP is a horrible protocol, and you are probably overflowing the routers connection tracking table. Try changing between passive and active ftp to see if that helps. Alternatively set up a VPN between the PC and vm to bypass the connection traffic, or upgrade the router to dd-wrt.

Comment: Or use another protocol like scp